# Wpf Caliburn.Micro view not loading

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mef, caliburn.micro

I am new to Wpf and Caliburn and I have the following scenario that i desire some help with, I am sure that the code is correct but this is not working as expected, to elaborate

My AppBootstrapper is thus:

```
public class AppBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
    private CompositionContainer _container;

    public AppBootstrapper()
    {
        this.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DisplayRootViewFor<ShellViewModel>();
    }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        try
        {
            this._container = new CompositionContainer(new AggregateCatalog(new DirectoryCatalog(".", "*")));

            var batch = new CompositionBatch();

            batch.AddExportedValue<IWindowManager>(new WindowManager());
            batch.AddExportedValue<IEventAggregator>(new EventAggregator());
            batch.AddExportedValue(this._container);
            this._container.Compose(batch);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this._log.Error(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
    {
        try
        {
            var contract = string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) ? AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(service) : key;
            var exports = this._container.GetExportedValues<object>(contract);

            if (exports.Any())
            {
                return exports.First();
            }

            throw new Exception(string.Format("Could not locate any instances of contract {0}.", contract));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex is ReflectionTypeLoadException)
            {
                var typeLoadException = ex as ReflectionTypeLoadException;
                var loaderExceptions = typeLoadException.LoaderExceptions;
                if (loaderExceptions != null)
                {
                    this._log.Error(loaderExceptions.First().ToString());
                }
            }

            throw;
        }
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
    {
        return this._container.GetExportedValues<object>(AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(service));
    }

    protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
    {
        this._container.SatisfyImportsOnce(instance);
    }
}
```

My ShellViewModel is as follows (i have removed some of the code to keep it short)

```
[Export(typeof(ShellViewModel))]
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>, 
                              IHandle<NavigationEvent>, 
                              IHandle<WindowCloseEnabledEvent>, 
                              IShell, 
                              IShellViewModel
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ShellViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        this._eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    }

    [Import(typeof(LoginViewModel))]
    public Lazy<IScreen> LoginViewModel { get; set; }

    public void Loaded()
    {
        this._eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
        this.ActivateItem(this.LoginViewModel.Value);
    }
}
```

I have an event trigger in the ShellView.xaml that triggers the Loaded method above.

I also have a LoginViewModel and LoginView (note that these are in ViewModels and Views folders in the project.

The important bit of LoginViewModel is

```
[Export(typeof(LoginViewModel))]
public class LoginViewModel : Screen, IAnimatableViewModel, ILoginViewModel
{
    protected override void OnViewLoaded(object view)
    {
        this._view = view;
        IoC.Get<ShellViewModel>().DisableClose = true;
        base.OnViewLoaded(view);
    }
}
```

And the LoginView.xaml at the moment simply displays some text.

I am using MEF as the DI container, the issue is that when I run up the application the ShellView is loaded which should load the LoginView into it but the LoginView does not load (or doesn't display)

If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Better mention and tag your DI container.

Comment: 1) Are you exporting LoginViewModel ?

Comment: @eran Yes I am exporting my LoginViewModel

Comment: @Henk I am using Caliburn.Micro

Comment: Yes, that was clear. But the question also involves your DI library (Unity/MEF/Autofac/...)

Comment: @Henk sorry misread your question I believe it is MEF

Comment: Are you sure that you bind LoginViewModel to ContentControl?  I always use `Conductor<T>.Collection.OneActive` or `Conductor<T>.Collection.AllActive`, the first hold many items but activates one at a time,  last all items are activated.  In documentation said `Conductor<T>` is implementation for holds and activates only one item at a time, I think that it is rarely scenario to use use Conductor<T>.